# Power Apps Sort Filter & Search

Tags: powerapps

I am having an issue combining a function in a power app I am building.  Each of the following statements work fine independently.

```
SortByColumns(
    If(Dropdown1.Selected.Status = "All", UAR_Access, 
        Filter(UAR_Access, Status = Dropdown1.Selected.Status)), 
   "LAST_x0020_NAME",
    If(srtDescending,
        Descending,
        Ascending))
```

and

```
Search(UAR_Access, Search_Txt.Text,"LAST_x0020_NAME", "FIRST_x0020_NAME")
```

My issue comes into play where I want to apply both statements to the same gallery. I am sure it can be done, I need some help with the syntax.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both [Filter and Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-filter-lookup) functions take and return a table, so they can be combined such that the result of one can be used as the parameter to the other, like in the example below:

```
SortByColumns(
    Search(
        If(
            Dropdown1.Selected.Status = "All",
            UAR_Access,
            Filter(UAR_Access, Status = Dropdown1.Selected.Status)),
        Search_Txt.Text,
        "LAST_x0020_NAME", "FIRST_x0020_NAME"),
   "LAST_x0020_NAME",
    If(srtDescending, SortOrder.Descending, SortOrder.Ascending))
```

Comment: that seems to have done the trick.  Thank you Carlos!